# Issue with applying style on WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, coding-style

I have a user-control and I want to use it in some other project. There is no problem when I set some value to its properties directly:

```
<local:MyUserControl prop1="val1" prop2="val2">
    ...
</local:MyUserControl>
```

But I can't apply a style to it. I tried:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyUserControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
            <Setter Property="prop1" Value="val1"/>
            <Setter Property="prop2" Value="val2"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlStyle}">
            ...
        </local:MyUserControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where did I wrong? -Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing an error, or are you just not seeing your style applied?

Comment: @Dan My user control is a scroll viewer that shows an animated arrow shaped button in every required side of its child. When I apply the style, arrow shaped buttons disappear. (I don't receive any error neither at desing-time nor at run-time.)

Comment: Where did you declared the Style tag? Is it included in a Resources section hierarchically ancestor of where the MyUserControl instance lies?

Comment: @Mario I'll edit the question and will give you a bigger picture.

Comment: Your Code in the shown example is correct. I just copied it, and it works.

Comment: @Mario I found some info about you on the web, but I couldn't find your email. Please send me an email to give you full source code.

Comment: My email should be visible on my StackOverflow profile. If not, you should find some articles reporting my email. Anyway: vernarim (at) libero (dot) it

Comment: Mario already asked for all possible failures I would ask for. So If he can't help you anymore, update your post. For example show the DP, getter/setter, or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using dear @Mario Vernari's instructions, I found it out that the problem was due to a bad strategy which I'd used to create my UserControl. I wanted to create a UserControl that be able to hold some other ones. So I had tried this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyUserControl"
             ...
             Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlStyle}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        ...
        <Style x:Key="MyUserControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=DP1}">
                            ...
                            <ContentPresenter ... Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            ...
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Where `DP1` is a dependency property of type `Brush`. The UserControl which has been created through this way works if you set its properties (like `DP1`) directly. Absolutely this is not the true way as @Mario told me:

> ...When you use an UserControl, it means that you *already* know its layout, and there is no need to style the control further. You are defining its style twice *at the same time* thus results a collision...

And he added:

> Instead, you should use a CustomControl; Define the default style in the *Themes* folder (if you own regular Visual Studio, it makes automatically). Afterward, you may *override* the default style in your own app. In the same way you would do for a normal base class and its derived.
>
> Follow this:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFCustomControl.aspx ...

Obviously, in this case we need to derive our lookless control from `ContentControl` class (instead of `Control` class). You may take a look at [this](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/02/05/creating-customized-usercontrols-deriving-from-contentcontrol-in-wpf-4) & [this](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/07/writing-reusable-custom-control-in-wpf.html) to master the details.

Here, I give thanks to @Mario again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlStyle}"`.

It's just - `Style="{StaticResource MyUserControlStyle}"`.

Comment: As I expected, This had no effect on it.

Comment: @Varun: The latter sample you give is just a shorthand for the first.  `ResourceKey` is the default property of the `StaticResource` markupextension and so you don't *have* to name it.