# using custom controls instead of user controls to create complex views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I do not have enough information about WPF, so please correct me.
It seems that to handle different views create many usercontrols is needed(each view needs one usercontol which binds to the viewModel) , and also by using MVVM pattern designers can create views independently. 
now if the designer tries to create two themes with different structure, he has to create two usercontrols because when using usercontrols the layout is specified(as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470621/issue-with-applying-style-on-wpf-usercontrol)).
on the other way customControls do not specify the layout, so it seems that using CustomControls is more reasonable. 
so the question: is using custom controls instead of usercontrols is correct, and if it is, is it reasonable for viewmodels to inherit from Control, and views become only styles for viewmodels?

Comment: `is it reasonable for viewmodels to inherit from Control` - No, of course not. ViewModel is an independent, UI-Framework-agnostic class that has no knowledge whatsoever about WPF or anything else. And no, you don't use `Controls` for Views. Otherwise you need `ControlTemplates` everywhere, which is not desired.

Comment: so is it possible too change the layout of usercontrol for different views, what is the solution? thanks

Comment: How many times will you really need that? You can also use `DataTemplates` for different `DataTypes` if needed. Does an application `Theme` significantly change the layout? Are you really sure you want that behavior in your application? And if so, you can still achieve this via regular `Styles` with `x:Key` for any given UIElement, which is loaded dynamically depending on the active `Theme`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you *need* the functionality provided by custom controls, I would suggest using UserControls or DataTemplates.  They are  simpler.  Here's a related question\answer.

[WPF User Controls vs Custom Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279852/wpf-user-controls-vs-custom-controls)