# UserControl styles not applied when embedded in a Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating a simple WPF Gui. I am trying to apply implicit styles to all UserControls to give them some default appearances - the background color, and font. This seems to work on the user control itself. However, when the user control is embedded in a Window the styles are list.

For example, here is a user control:

[image: UserControl]

Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NtpClient.Gui.Components.MainPanel.MainPanelView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:serverSelector="clr-namespace:NtpClient.Gui.Components.ServerSelector"
        xmlns:detailsPanel="clr-namespace:NtpClient.Gui.Components.DetailsPanel"

        Height="350" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <serverSelector:ServerSelectorView Grid.Column="0" Padding="6" />
        <detailsPanel:DetailsPanelView Grid.Column="1" Padding="6" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the Window with the UserControl in:

[image: Window]

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="NtpClient.Gui.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mainPanel="clr-namespace:NtpClient.Gui.Components.MainPanel"
        Title="Network Time Servers" Height="350" Width="400">
    <mainPanel:MainPanelView Width="auto" Height="auto"/>
</Window>
```

The Themes file is set in `app.xaml` and looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes_CoreThemes;component/ControlStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes_CoreThemes;component/BrushResources.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    

    <!-- Implicit Styles -->
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DeepBlueButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlStyle}" TargetType="UserControl" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="NtpClient.Gui.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes_CoreThemes;component/ControlStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes_CoreThemes;component/BrushResources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Local/Local.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this, and how I resolve it?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470621/issue-with-applying-style-on-wpf-usercontrol

Answer (score -1):

I've faces that problem some month's ago.
It's because your xaml files are in other dll's.
I don't know why, but designer isn't handling that properly.
Look like it's external issue of Designer.
I've just moved styles from dll's to the main project.